# Como validar URL em php?

Tags: php

Como faço para validar uma URL em php? Exemplo: preciso que o usuario digite uma url, ex: google.com.br.

Porem preciso que a url esteja no formato: www.google.com.br e se ele digitar qualquer formato diferente desse retorne um erro para ele corrigir.

Se ele digitar paginas especificas tambem. Exemplo www.google.com.br/imagens. Preciso que ele valide somente até o .br ou .com etc...somente até o dominio. Como faço?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi meu problema galera,usando http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php.

Exemplo:

```
$url = parse_url('http://facebook.com.br/imagens');
unset($url['host']); 
unset($url['scheme']);
if (count($url)) //url inválida
```